# ¿Cómo puedo dividir minutos a segundos en un ActionPerformed JAVA?

Tags: java, date, java-swing, interfaz-gráfica, timer

Ayuda, estoy desarrollando un proyecto en el que dependiendo el tiempo (**tiempototal**) que la persona quiera correr se le irán asignando 4 tipos de ejercicios (Caminar, correr, trotar y otra).

Lo que sucede es que quiero que se divida el tiempo (**tiempototal**) entre esos 4 ejercicios, por ejemplo:
Al poner 3 minutos de ejercicio que se le asignen 45 segundos a cada uno mientras el tiempo esté corriendo (0, 45, 90, 135).

```
    private ActionListener acciones = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        TiempoElegido = Integer.valueOf(txtTiempo.getText());
        centesimas_Segundos++;
        
        int TiempoElegidoASegundos = TiempoElegido*60;
    
        
        //Division en Segundos
          int    divisionEjercicio1S = TiempoElegidoASegundos/4;
          int    divisionEjercicio2S = divisionEjercicio1S+divisionEjercicio1S;
          int    divisionEjercicio3S =  divisionEjercicio2S+divisionEjercicio1S;
          //Division en Minutos
          
          int    divisionEjercicio1M = (TiempoElegido*3600)/4;
          int    divisionEjercicio2M = divisionEjercicio1M/divisionEjercicio1M;
          int    divisionEjercicio3M = divisionEjercicio2M+divisionEjercicio1M;
          
          
          
          if(centesimas_Segundos== 01 && segundos ==0){
                etiqueta_Ejercicio.setText("Caminar Prueba");
          }
          
        if (centesimas_Segundos == 100) {
            segundos++;
            centesimas_Segundos = 0;
          
        }
        
        if(segundos == divisionEjercicio1S && minutos ==divisionEjercicio1M){
            
            etiqueta_Ejercicio.setText("Correr Prueba");                              
            
        }
        if(segundos==divisionEjercicio2S && minutos == divisionEjercicio2M){
            etiqueta_Ejercicio.setText("Trotar");
        }
        if (segundos == divisionEjercicio3S && minutos == divisionEjercicio3M){
            etiqueta_Ejercicio.setText("LOCO");
        }
        
        
        
        
        if (segundos == 60) {
            minutos++;
            segundos = 0;
        }
        if (minutos == 60) {
            horas++;
            minutos = 0;
        }
        if (minutos == TiempoElegido) {
            tiempo.stop();
            etiqueta_Ejercicio.setText("Finalizado, buen trabajo!");
        }

        ActualizarEtiquetaTiempo();
    }
};
```

Eso es lo que llevo hasta ahora y me ha funcionado sólo con segundos pero me he estancado.

Comment: Una opción es que trabajes todo en segundos :)